# What is the technical name for the stopper used to seal a barrel of beer or wine?

Tags: terminology, barrels

Most fermenting vessels require a stopper to hold an airlock in place or seal it up while moving so what is the technical name of that stopper?

Comment: Bung. The hole is called the bung hole and now you know where that term came from!

Answer (score 3):

The stopper is called a “bung”. The hole is called the bung hole.

> A bung, stopper or cork is a truncated cylindrical or conical closure to seal a container, such as a bottle, tube or barrel. Unlike a lid, which encloses a container from the outside without displacing the inner volume, a bung is partially inserted inside the container to act as a seal. - [Bung (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bung)

[image: Bung]

Bung in the bunghole of a wine barrel

Comment: Thank you @Eric Shain

Comment: @kengraham Thanks for the edits!